# Formating lua code - any tool?

Tags: lua

Hi so i recently decoded some game scripts written in lua. But it looks like this
[My code looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SiTw.png)

```
PlayerTable = {          JOGO = 0,          BALANCE = 0,          BALANCE_P = 0,          PROFIT = 0,          XXX = 0,          XXX_Count = 0,          XXX_Player = 0,          AH,          AL,          NUM,          LOSETOP = {            Times = 0,            Money = 0,            Name          },          WINTOP = {            Times = 0,            Money = 0,            Name          }        }      end      if PlayerTable.JOGO == Games.NULL then        if 0 < PlayerTable.BALANCE then          if table.contains(words.H, Message) then            PlayerTable.JOGO = Games.HIGH            if HL_ENABLED then              Last_Payout = os.time()              MinOption = BetOption[PlayerTable.JOGO].Min              MaxOption = BetOption[PlayerTable.JOGO].Max              PayoutOption = BetOption[PlayerTable.JOGO].Payout            else              if not table.contains(LimitSay.DISABLED, name) then                Self.Say(Disabled_G[PlayerTable.JOGO])                table.insert(LimitSay.DISABLED, name)              end              PlayerTable.JOGO = Games.NULL            end          elseif table.contains(words.L, Message) then            PlayerTable.JOGO = Games.LOW            if HL_ENABLED then
```

I know there are HTML, JS etc. beautifiers so Is there any tool i can use to beautify this code ? 
Or do i need to do it manually ? Its almost 2000 lines of code so i would rather not to do this manually.

Comment: please use websearch for things like that... also read [ask]

Answer (score -2):

You could use ZeroBrane. Basically select the code and then Edit-> Source -> Correct Indentation